# Can I delegate windows service execution to another process?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I would like to be able to have a Windows service start, launch another executable, and then exit, leaving the launched executable to run in place of itself as the service.

The processes will be able to communicate with each other, so any information needed in either process from the other process is available.

Is this possible to do in .NET?

**EDIT:** To clarify, here's what the workflow would look like:

1. Service starts, launching a.exe. Note: a.exe does *not* call ServiceBase.Run()
2. a.exe launches b.exe using Process.Start()
3. a.exe and b.exe accomplish any communication required to exchange information, such as process or service handles (Note: this functionality already exists)
4. a.exe assigns service control to b.exe
5. a.exe exits, leaving b.exe running and bound to the service control

Comment: If the service process exits *"The processes will be able to communicate with each other"* is not going to be possible.

Comment: Erm, how will they communicate if the service exits?  How is the admin supposed to stop and restart the service?  It really isn't a service anymore, just a process that nobody has any control over.

Comment: Steps 4 and 5 are of course the rub, you can't make that happen.  The service controller only knows of services it started.  The service control callback is process specific.  Use the ServiceController class to control b.exe, it needs to be a service as well.

Comment: @DanielShaffer if you can manage to pass the process ID for b.exe back to the service, you should be able to control it. You might consider extended whatever communications mechanism you're using to talk between a.exe and b.exe to allow b.exe to talk to the service. One way to do ths would be to open a socket connection between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't change the the process that is bound to the service control manager.  To see why this is impossible you need to see how the unmanaged Windows service API works. (which .NET is wrapping).

You connect to the service control manager by calling [StartServiceCtrlDispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which can only be called once).  In the `lpServiceTable` parameter you pass a pointer to a `ServiceMain` function, which obviously is only valid for the current process and all of the service control notifications are sent to this function.

The call to `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` also does not return until all the services have stopped.  So the service control  managed is also tied to a thread in process that started the service, so that can't exit without the link to the service manager being severed.

So in your example, step 4 cannot occur, and process a.exe needs to stay alive for the duration.

Comment: What if I created a SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY with the handle of the launched process instead of the current one? I realize I'd basically be re-implementing ServiceBase.Run(), but it seems like that could do it?

Comment: No, the SERVICE_ENTRY_TABLE doesn't contain a handle to a process - it always uses the current process.

Answer (score 0):

See [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), [this tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ProcessStart.aspx) (old, but should still work), [or this one](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start).

If you're trying to start a service that's already registered, [this may help](http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/).

Once the new process is running, communication with it has the same requirements as any other interprocess communications secnario.

You could use WCF, open a socket, use a database, etc. Without more details about what sort of communication you need, it's difficult to recommend a particular approach.

Comment: I already use Process.Start to launch the second process. IPC is already taken care of - I only mentioned in the question to show that it is available if needed. What I'm mainly interested in is getting the service control bound to the second process instead of the first.